# Какое задать условие чтобы клетка на переписывалась(крестики-нолики)

Tags: java, консоль

```
char[][] humanTurn(char[][]arr, int size,char DOT)throws  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {

    int x;
    int y;
    do {


           System.out.println("\nвведите строку и строчку через пробел");

        x = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
        y = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
        System.out.println(x +""+ y);
        arr[x][y] = DOT;

            System.out.println("\nневерно");

        //   System.out.println(123);
        //  System.out.println(map[x][y]);
    } while (((x>size)&(y>size)&(x<=0)&(y<=0))&(arr[x][y]!= DOT));// todo условие чтобы клетка со знаком 'X' или 'O' не переписывалась
    System.out.println(x+""+y);
    return arr;
}
```

пишу крестики нолики, не могу понять 2 вещи, как записать exception для неверного значения в nextInt(NAN) и тут же его еще и на ArrayOutOfBounds проверить, и как запретить переписывание клетки в которой уже сделан ход, думаю в условии while написать что-то вроде arr[x][y]=DOT_X; arr[x][y]=DOT_O, или заменить arr[x][y]!=DOT_N('*')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ну с логическим мышлением у вас туга точно.(строка и строчка одно и то же.)
2. если вы словами можете объяснить что вы хотите значит это можно написать.
   Как не заполнять занятую ячейку? (может проще проверять пуста она или нет, ведь незаполненность тоже состояние а следовательно условие будет..)

```
    arr[x][y] == emptyDOT
```

3. Проверку на принадлежность к диапазону лучше отдельно

```
    private boolen isCellInMap(int _row , int _col){
        //TODO: просто ретурн с условием и нет проблем
    }
```